# adding a class to an element depending on a Json feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spreadsheet

Hit a slight bump on something.

So I have a spreadsheet feed coming through via json.

Once they are loaded, if they contain a certain word, I want an elment that is already on the page to do something.

Having some trouble.

Here is my code:

```
      /*feed*/

        function displayContent(json) {
var len = json.feed.entry.length
var divtag = ''
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    divtag += [
        '<div id=' +' tooltipwrap' + i  + '>'  +
        '<span style="font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">',
        json.feed.entry[i].gsx$studentname.$t + ' ' +  
         '<span class="hide"  style="font-size:18px; font-weight:300;">',
        json.feed.entry[i].gsx$classlevel.$t
        +  '</span>' + '<span id=' + 'tooltipside' + i +'>' + 
         json.feed.entry[i].gsx$gender.$t + '-' +
        '</span>',


        '</div>'

        ].join(''); 
        }
document.getElementById('tipswrap').innerHTML = divtag
    }
```

/* what I wanted to do */

```
     if ($('#tooltipside0').html() === "Senior") {
           $("#test1").addClass('no');
     }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/pWNSc/3/) is the JSFiddle

Comment: You know your html is not valid? `'<div id=' +' tooltipwrap' + i  + '>'` & `'<span id=' + 'tooltipside' + i +'>'` the IDs are not wrapped in quotes

Comment: You're also missing a close span, take a look at my answer for the fixed html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pay attention to the tabulation. Right now your code is hard to read because you have failed to do so.
2. Here:

   var len = json.feed.entry.length
   var divtag = ''

you are missing semi-colons. You have to put semi-colon at the end of any operation, like this:

```
var len = json.feed.entry.length;
var divtag = '';
```

Semi-colons serve as operation separators.

1. Here:

divtag += [
    ''  +
    '',
    json.feed.entry[i].gsx$studentname.$t + ' ' +
     '',
    json.feed.entry[i].gsx$classlevel.$t
    +  '' + '' + 
     json.feed.entry[i].gsx$gender.$t + '-' +
    '',

```
'</div>'

].join('');
```

You have multiple problems:

You have failed to put your html attributes into quotes, so the resulting html will be invalid. Also, you have used comma instead of plus at the last concatenation.

CONCLUSION: You are obviously not ready to implement this code, because:

```
- You lack Javascript syntax knowledge
- You lack HTML syntax knowledge
- You do not pay attention to tabulation
```

As a consequence, your main problem is not what the question states, namely, how to add a class to an element depending on JSON feed. Your main problem is that you lack Javascript and HTML education. Please, follow some tutorials to be able to solve a problem and after that try again to solve your problem. If you fail to do so, then you will have at least an educated guess.

Comment: appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Cleaned up my html and my original if statements worked fine...has been some time since I adde din html through JS so, not surprised it was wonky. Thanks for the evaluation lol

Answer (score 1):

After adding the content to `tipswrap` add the condition

```
 document.getElementById('tipswrap').innerHTML = divtag; //$('#tipswrap').html(divtag)
 if ($.trim($('#tooltipside0').html()) === "Senior") {
       $("#test1").addClass('no');
 }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vCCfK/)

Comment: now what if I have to do the same thing..but to multiple elements? lets say I have 3 options addClass('no'), addClass('yes'), addClass(maybe)  and for multiple elements like #tooltipside0, #tooltipside1, #tooltipside2, etc etc  ?

Comment: @gregdsign how will be the condition? will it always against `"Senior"` or some other value

Comment: All set, It turned out to be some of my wonky html.....I havent written HTML via JS in quite some time so, I had a suspicion.

Comment: I cleaned it up and added back my original if statements..works perfectly...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you add a class to all of your rows called `student` and then from there use this javascript:

```
function displayContent(json) {
  var len = json.feed.entry.length
  var divtag = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    divtag += 
      '<div class="student" id="tooltipwrap'+i+'">'+
        '<span style="font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">'+
          json.feed.entry[i].gsx$studentname.$t +
          '<span class="hide" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:300;">'+
            json.feed.entry[i].gsx$classlevel.$t +
          '</span> '+
          '<span id="tooltipside'+i+'">'+
            json.feed.entry[i].gsx$gender.$t + '-' +
          '</span>'+
        '</span>'+
      '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('tipswrap').innerHTML = divtag
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.student').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("senior") >= 0)
      $(this).addClass('senior');
  });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/pWNSc/8/)

Comment: thank you so much...shoot I missed that my quotes were off making my html invalid..checking your fiddle now

Comment: @gregdsign No problem! Mind up-voting my answer? I'm trying to get to 1000 rep tonight

Comment: Mind giving me an example? Say you have 3 students, 1 of each, what should be added to `#test1`? And what about other scenarios (no freshman or no junior or no senior)?

Comment: Im all set... turned out to be my wonky HTML....havent writen out divs, spans etc through JS like that in a while so, had a feeling my code wasnt valid...I added my if statements back from my original example and works perfectly...thank you though for heading me in the right direction!